# adsense is not showing in mobile phone

Tags: adsense

hi my adsense is working just fine in all pages i open in desktop but when i open the same  thing in mobile 99% of times adsense is not showing ads and in few times it is showing.
i have choosen automatic size so size should not be a problem and seems  everything is fine but i tried chrome and other browsers but i am not getting anything in most of the browsers when opened from mobile but same thing works fine when opened from desktop it serves ads.

```
      example pages http://way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/photos-slideshow-m.php/2503997
```

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the source of your html page I see a lot of html errors, like analytics codes above the `<html>` tag. First fix all those errors and try again.